# HTML form input with special chars

Tags: html, forms

Whenever I try to submit a text containing special chars like `&amp;`, via a HTML form in a `<textarea>`, some chars are lost. (tested in Chrome browser)

So far, I could not find a form attribute to change this behaviour.

How to force the form to submit the input without this loss?

Comment: Have you set the proper encoding in your HTML HEAD section (META)

Comment: the form is static, no javascript, only a plain html form.

Comment: What do you mean by “ special chars like `&amp;`”? That’s just five common Ascii characters. Please provide a full testable document that illustrates the issue and specify some specific input that triggers the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The children of a `textarea` are bog-standard text nodes. The element doesn't perform any automatic CDATA magic (like a `script` does).

If you have `<textarea>&amp;</textarea>` then that means "A textarea element with a default value of 'an ampersand'".

If you want `"&amp;"` to be the submitted data, then you have to represent the `&` with a character reference, just like (almost) anywhere else in HTML: `<textarea>&amp;amp;</textarea>`

OTOH, if you are **typing** `&amp;` and the `amp;` part is being lost, then it is probably because you are taking the value of that form control and treating it as *HTML* when you want to treat it as *text*. How you treat it as text instead of HTML depends on what you are using to process the data.

Comment: how to work around this issue? the browser is cutting/treating the chars, not the script afterwards and not me. anyways, i'd like to get it fixed, e.g. with a javascript that catches the input without dropping parts of it. any idea to get this done?